# Difference between simple space and &nbsp;

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between a simple space (created with the keyboard space key) and `&nbsp;` (HTML No-break space)?

I asked this because when I used both (simple space and `&nbsp;`) on my page they behave differently.

In my web application when I put a simple space (with keyboard space key) into a `span`, it  has no height or width (0px) but when I put `&nbsp` into the `span` it has a height and width.

When I tried this same thing with `div` tag, the same problem occurred.

[See in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA8ez/1/)

In jsfiddle you can see that when I use a simple space, the element doesn't have a height (it's always `0px`), but when I use `&nbsp;`, it has a height.

Answer (score 6):

`nbsp` stands for *non-breaking space* and there are mainly two differences:

1. With a normal whitespace character, the content will be wrapped around if there is no horizontal space anymore. So, `foo bar` might be rendered as

   ```
    foo
    bar
   ```

   whereas `foo&nbsp;bar` will always be rendered as

   ```
   foo bar
   ```

   If there is not enough horizontal space, the content just overflows.
2. The browser can decide to trim whitespace characters at the beginning or end of the content of an HTML element. This is described in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1):

   > In order to avoid problems with SGML line break rules and inconsistencies among extant implementations, authors should not rely on user agents to render white space immediately after a start tag or immediately before an end tag.

   This means that `<div> foo bar </div>` is interpreted by the browser as `<div>foo bar</div>` and hence `<div> </div>` as `<div></div>` (i.e. as an empty element).

Answer (score 1):

A non-breaking space and a normal space is different. A non-­breaking space acts like a magnet, keeping words or characters connected either side of the space, prevents an automatic line break at its position .
EX: July 20 2018

Non Breaking prevents from non breaking and having ASCII even different when compared to normal space .

ASCII of non breakable space is 160

ASCII of normal space is 32.

Answer (score 0):

Well ya there is the difference between `&nbsp;` and Simple Space. `&nbsp;` is Refers as 
Non-Breaking Space in Html means it wont break with the ending of line and you can find better explanation here

http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm

looking forward for space it will collapse if you use it more then one time in you project and ya that is the basic difference and you can find other also in that link.